# Ensuring same results for different engines when inspecting a variable in a l3build regression test

Tags: l3build

Some days ago I read a discussion in chat about getting the same output for different engines while testing for typeset material with `l3build` (https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62890308#62890308), and it turns out it is possible to do so when the font used is the same. The benefit is that we can just save the test result for the default engine, then check all engines against the same .tlg file.

I was playing with this today and, despite following that tip, I still get some differences across engines of a different nature, but when inspecting variables. If the line which asked to show a variable is somewhat long, the truncation seems do be different between the `pdftex` and `luatex` engines.

Consider the following setup. A `build.lua` with:

```lua
bundle = ""
module = "mypackage"

checkengines = {"pdftex","luatex","xetex"}
```

And a test file `testfiles/test1.lvt` with:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\input{regression-test}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_my_var_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_my_var_tl {foo}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\START

\ExplSyntaxOn
\BEGINTEST{Inspecting~a~variable}
Some long line which happens to also show a variable.\tl_show:N \l_my_var_tl
\ENDTEST
\ExplSyntaxOff

\OMIT

\end{document}
```

If I save the test results for `pdftex` with `l3build save -e pdftex test1` then run `l3build check` the `luatex` check fails. And the `test1.luatex.diff` is:

```
*** ./build/test/test1.luatex.tlg   2023-02-10 21:45:48.607269954 -0300
--- ./build/test/test1.luatex.log   2023-02-10 21:45:48.607269954 -0300
***************
*** 5,9 ****
  ============================================================
  > \l_my_var_tl=foo.
  <recently read> }
! l. ......so show a variable.\tl_show:N \l_my_var_tl
  ============================================================
--- 5,9 ----
  ============================================================
  > \l_my_var_tl=foo.
  <recently read> }
! l. ......also show a variable.\tl_show:N \l_my_var_tl
  ============================================================
```

So, the way the line in which the inspected variable is called ends up in the log, but the truncation of the line differs in a couple of characters.

Is there a way to avoid this? And thus be able to save a single .tlg file for this test?

Comment: l3build tries to normalise things but luatex has a habit of being different by one column which can make it hard. You can maxmise the number of characters in a log line so tex does not wrap the output. Also use \show at the start of a lines so you do  not have the ... context

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So this is a known thing?... In practice, in the real use case the \show occurs inside a command which I'm interested in, so there's nothing to trim out, and the line can be long. I'm not sure setting longer lines for the log is attractive, and if it will be enough in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

l3build tries to normalise things but luatex has a habit of being different by one column which can make it hard. You can maxmise the number of characters in a log line so tex does not wrap the output. Also use \show at the start of a lines so you do not have the ... context

This version passes for example

```
\documentclass{article}

\input{regression-test}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_my_var_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_my_var_tl {foo}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\START

\ExplSyntaxOn
\BEGINTEST{Inspecting~a~variable}
Some long line which happens to also show a variable.
\tl_show:N \l_my_var_tl
\ENDTEST
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn
\BEGINTEST{Inspecting~a~variable2}
Some long line which happens to also show a variable.\typeout{\meaning\l_my_var_tl}
\ENDTEST
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn
\BEGINTEST{Inspecting~a~variable3}
\tl_new:N \l_my_varref_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_my_varref_tl {foo}
Some long line which happens to also show a variable. \ifx\l_my_var_tl\l_my_varref_tl\TRUE\else\FALSE\fi
\ENDTEST
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn
\BEGINTEST{Inspecting~a~variable4}
\newcommand{\testtmp}{Some long line which happens to also show a variable.\tl_show:N \l_my_var_tl}
\testtmp
\ENDTEST
\ExplSyntaxOff

\OMIT

\end{document}
```

Comment: David, thanks. So indeed there's nothing that can be done in the normalization side of things. In my real use case, I'm typesetting a macro of interest inside of which I add some inspection points depending on a boolean which I enable in the test files. So I'm not sure if I'll be able to circumvent this this way. But I'll try your suggestions, Thank you!

Comment: @gusbrs `\typeout{\meaning\l_my_var_tl}` just shows the meaning without the context lines so is easier to handle than \show`

Comment: I'll try that out. And I had a little other idea too, to define a short variable and call it. Let's see if I can curb down my .tlgs. ;-)

Comment: David, may I add a fourth workaround to the mix? Also, in your experience, do you see any adverse side effects of setting a large `maxprintline` for test files?

Comment: @gusbrs as I suggested in comments under the question but not here maximising maxprintline  has advantages, the main reason we haven't done it for the latex tests is it would change the output of thousands (or hundreds perhaps) of existing tests. But it was added to l3build to save you fiddling with  texmf.cnf defaults specifically because making it big is useful. (You could post that as a 2nd answer if it fixes this case, it's a bit different so does not really fit this answer)

Comment: I'll try `maxprintline` too, since I'm bound to revise the test files anyway. And, the other workaround is just in line with the ones you suggested in your answer, and would fit well there, I'd say.

Comment: @gusbrs ah sorry I thought you meant maxprintline  as 4th, feel free to edit this post as you wish

Comment: For the record, setting a large `maxprintline` seems useful but, as far as I can tell, has no bearing on the particular problem of this question.

Comment: @ DavidCarlisle I guess Joseph just changed his mind about `maxprintline`... It is a good idea in the longer term, but damn...  :-(

Comment: @gusbrs l3build does set maxprintline it (now) defaults to `l3build-variables.lua:maxprintline = maxprintline or 9999`

Comment: @ DavidCarlile, I mean the latest `l3build` release, in particular https://github.com/latex3/l3build/commit/fd19f1dcd0edfbb72606d431893964f521333874 (I've been rechecking diff hunks for hours now already...)

Comment: oh I see.......

Comment: @gusbrs The change is mentioned in the manual: the reality here is that if you want a complete non-variant check system you need your own copy so you can update it only when you want

Comment: @gusbrs Why are you checking diffs? You should be able to locally know that you had a passing state, and thus all changes are due to the `l3build` update and can be checked in

Comment: @gusbrs You can always set the value for the wrapping in a local `.cfg` to whatever you like

Comment: @JosephWright I don't have the luxury of an environment controlled to this degree. Tests are run with the latest in TL, `l3build` included. And I'm checking diffs for the same reason I'd only use `--show-saves` very carefully, when I'm sure of the sources of all changes. Since the changes happened "upstream", I cannot isolate, so I have to check.

Comment: @gusbrs Presumably on your local machine you can checkout `l3build`, do a local install of the previous release, etc., if necessary

Comment: @JosephWright Regarding a local `.cfg`, I agree, it is better not to wrap. It is just that I used defaults when I started, and now have to adjust to the change. I doubt I'll be the only one though.

Comment: @gusbrs No, you won't be the only one: we always give it some thought before we adjust the normalisation or standard settings, but line wrapping (again) was causing some issues in normalisation, so I had to make a judgement

Comment: @JosephWright I know that. And don't worry, it is fine really. It just is what it is, it comes with a cost. ;-)

Comment: @gusbrs you are not alone, I adjusted this morning lots of tagpdf tests ;-) But generally: it is faster to rebuild all tests (with or without -show-saves) and then check the difference in some diff viewer with a side-by-side view of the files (I used gitkraken where I can staged directly.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer :-) That's more or less what I do. I save every failing test, then check the diffs in Magit status buffer before actually committing. But when things bet this large https://github.com/gusbrs/zref-clever/commit/de73d3212839d3c7ae62372d20b3faf9433ca444 it's still a lot.